# Rails Repetitive Background Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, background-process

I'm not sure what the best solution/practice is for Rails so I thought I'd ask here.

I need to have a background job or some kind of service that runs every 5 minutes to calculate the rankings for a game for tens of thousands of users, and possibly very soon, hundreds of thousands of users. The resulting array would then be accessed for each request that needs to determine a ranking.

What are people using ***these days*** for this? A cron and rake task? The daemon gem? Resque or Beanstalkd?

Thanks for listening :)

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions, I'm gonna try out Clockwork per kishie's recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I used [Clockwork gem](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) with [Delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) for the problem like you have

Answer (score 2):

We had similar requirement for an application we developed. We used

[whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for scheduling cron jobs and [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) for background processing.

Whenever would trigger a cron every 5 minutes which would conditionally put an entry in the delayed job queue.

We could have also used [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). Look at the comparison between delayed_job and resque to know what works best for you.